# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx $, is the same as $\int_{-1}^{0} (1-x^2)^n \ dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

This is stated without proof in baby rudin Theorem 7.26.
The natural way of doing this is using changes of variables and doing something like substiting $dx$ by $d(-x)$. However, rudin only stated and proved changes of variables for "increasing" maps. More precisely, this is the changes of variables theorem in rudin.

> Suppose $\phi$ is a strictly increasing continuous function that maps an interval $[A, B]$ onto $[a, b]$. Suppose $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[a, b]$ and $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Define $\beta$ and $g$ on $[A, B]$ by
> \begin{equation}
> \beta(y) = \alpha(\phi(y)), \quad g(y) = f(\phi(y)).
> \end{equation}
> Then $g \in \mathcal{R}(\beta)$ and
> \begin{equation}
> \int_{A}^{B} g \, d\beta = \int_{a}^{b} f \, d\alpha.
> \end{equation}

Thus setting $\phi(x) = -x$ is not yet allowed in rudin.
So how can I prove it?

Comment: $f(x)=f(-x)$ is all you need

Comment: This symmetry implies, for example, that the set of lower and upper sums for the two integrals are the same.

Comment: Another more intuitive method: Let $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_m=1$ be a partition and $\sum_{i=1}^m (1-\xi_i^2)^n (x_i-x_{i-1})$ be a Riemann sum. Then consider the partition $-1=-x_m<-x_{m-1}<\cdots<-x_1<-x_0=0$ and the Riemann sum $\sum_{i=1}^m (1-(-\xi_i)^2)^n ((-x_{i-1})-(-x_i))$. This Riemann sum is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^m (1-\xi_i^2)^n (x_i-x_{i-1})$. I left the succeeding argument to you.

Answer (score 0):

I want to change this question to prove that:
**$\int_{0}^{x}(1-t^2)^ndt=\int_{-x}^{0}(1-t^2)^ndt$**
So we set $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(1-t^2)^ndt$ and also $G(x)\int_{-x}^{0}(1-t^2)^ndt$
Then we first know F(0)=0=G(0),
Also we have the fundamental theorem of calculus, also the chain rule.
Then $F'(x)=(1-x^2)^n~and~\begin{aligned}G'(x)&=(-\int_{0}^{-x}(1-t^2)^ndt)'\\&=-(1-x^2)^n(-x)'\\&=(1-x^2)^n\end{aligned}$
So now what we have is $F(0)=G(0),~also~F'(x)=G'(x).$
So we will got $F(1)=G(1)$
Which means we have proved $\int_{0}^{1}(1-t^2)^ndt=\int_{-1}^{0}(1-t^2)^ndt$
I hope it will help.